# List the projection & datum of all the files in a folder

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, grass-gis

In QGIS/GRASS, is it possible to list the projection details of all the shp,tab,dxf files in a folder ? We are having 100 - 150 files in too many folders. We would like to create a table of Proj details of all the files in those folders. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL ogrinfo is able to report the projection information of shapefiles.

You can use it recursively in batch mode in OSGeo4w or Linux/Mac Terminal. The command line for recursion is dependent on the operating system.

For Windows, try:

```
for /R .\ %%N IN (*.shp) DO ogrinfo -al -so %%N >>outogr.txt
```

or using gdalsrsinfo on the .prj file:

```
for /R .\ %%N IN (*.shp) DO (echo %%N >>outprj.txt & gdalsrsinfo %%~nN.prj >>outprj.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But, i am very much new to python/command line/etc... So i dont know how to proceed.

I've installed FWTools (even from QGIS we can access this, rite ?) & figured out ogrinfo -so (Summary only) will do the job for me (think so). But don't know how to set the path for a particluar folder and export the result a csv or table.. Could you shed light on how i have to proceed ? Will be immensely helpful.

Comment: ogrinfo -al -so Folder_Path is listing all the details of the shapefiles in a particular folder. More or less, this is wat i am looking for. Only few things..

1) Won't it read the tab or dxf files in those folders ?

2) How to export this summary into a csv file or txt or table ?

3) is it possbile to use this as a python script in QGIS ?

Comment: Command line is different from python console. You have not told me which operating system you are using. This is essential for the command line recursion syntax.

Comment: We are using Windows 7 Professional

I am trying with this one For /R "Folder_Path" %f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so %f >> Projection.txt

It reads all the tab file. But, it says "Access is denied"

Comment: Not sure about the .tab, I don't have any. See my extended answer for shapefiles.

Comment: Actually, this command works fine for me

For /R Folder_Path %f in (*.tab) do ogrinfo -al -so "%f" >>Out.txt

One final hurdle is, will it able to save in a perfect csv format..so that we can open it straight away in an excel. The extension Out.csv works fine..but there was no separation between the texts

Thanks a lot Andre. Will try it with your code.

Comment: You need to do a bit handwork on the result because SRS is reported for every layer of a shapefile.

Comment: Yep..Will do that. 

But, by any chance is it possible to have the output text file without those "Had to open that data, INFO: Open of.." Coz, we have 100+ files in a folder. So doing this in excel is somewhat irritating.

Comment: Without the "Open of ..." you will not see what file is currently processed. I see no more options to reduce the output.